# How to avoid one observable variable in RXJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a state of the last rotation:

```
 public rotate$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);
```

This subjects is chnaged by:

```
rotateChanged$.subscribe((rotate: number) => {
    this.rotate$.next(rotate);
});
```

Where `rotateChnaged$` is:

```
const rotateChanged$ = merge(left$, right$).pipe(
        startWith(0),
        scan((acc, value) => acc + value, 0),
        map((rotation) => rotation * rotateAngle),
    );
```

I need to be able set `rotate$` from outside by default value.
Question is coould I use only one rxjs variable to manage rotation? Now I use `rotateChanged$` and `rotate$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is that there is something that generates 2 streams of events, `left$` and `right$`.

Then there is `rotateChanged$` that transforms these 2 streams into a new stream which notifies the rotation value.

Then eventually there are some consumers that want to know the rotation which subscribe to `rotate$`.

First consideration is that you could use a `Subject` and not a `BehaviourSubject` since there is a `startWith` operator in the pipe chain which builds `rotateChanged$`.

Second, let's try to answer your question. I guess you use a `Subject` because there are, at least potentially, more than one consumer which want to know the rotation and you want just ONE stream to provide these information (in other words you want to multicast the `rotation` stream). If this is the case, you can use the operator `share` in the pipe and provide, as API, only `rotateChanged$`.

In this case, you would not need `rotate$` and you would just publish `rotateChanged$` coded as follows

```
const rotateChanged$ = merge(left$, right$).pipe(
        startWith(0),
        scan((acc, value) => acc + value, 0),
        map((rotation) => rotation * rotateAngle),
        share(),
    );
```

Consider that `share`, internally, would use a `Subject` to obtain the result.